# Can anyone explain to me the libart_fake in the Android P source code

Tags: android

art/libart_fake/fake.cc:

```
namespace art {
class Dbg {
 public:
  void SuspendVM();
  void ResumeVM();
};

class FaultManager {
 public:
  void EnsureArtActionInFrontOfSignalChain();
};

void Dbg::SuspendVM() {
  LOGIT("Linking to and calling into libart.so internal functions is not supported. "
        "This call to '%s' is being ignored.", __func__);
}
void Dbg::ResumeVM() {
  LOGIT("Linking to and calling into libart.so internal functions is not supported. "
        "This call to '%s' is being ignored.", __func__);
}
void FaultManager::EnsureArtActionInFrontOfSignalChain() {
  LOGIT("Linking to and calling into libart.so internal functions is not supported. "
        "This call to '%s' is being ignored.", __func__);
}
};  // namespace art
```

art/libart_fake/README.md:

> A fake libart made to satisfy some misbehaving apps that will attempt
>   to link against libart.so.

I don't understand what is said in the readme. Who can explain it to me? Thank you very much.

Is the "link against libart.so" mentioned here dlopen? Or is it a static link?